# How to draw pointed border on the left of TextView with bullet to each TextView

Tags: android

I have about 5 to 10 TextViews which shows the stops, I want to add the bullet point on the left of the each TextView, but that point should be attached with the dotted line as shown in the image below.

As you can see in the photo there are three TextView/EditText with the bullets and each bullet is connected with the dotted line.

[image]

Comment: Why not use a drawable to the left of the text? You could draw the necessary variations of the icons, probably only two or three, so that they fit correctly.

Comment: I know about the drawableLeft but don't know how to manage the a line on the left with the bullet.

Comment: The dashed line could be a part of the icons. You would probably draw three icons (starting bullet, middle bullet and final marker). Considering the magin between the EditTexts though, you'd probably have to use the icons in a separate LinearLayout for them to fit and look as a single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using one horizontal LinearLayout as a parent and two vertical LinearLayout as the children, you can easily achieve what you want. You can change the padding/margin of your drawbles to change the views accroding to your preferences. Here is the XML code and a screenshot of the resultant layout for what you have in mind:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="doitfast.testapp.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radio_1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radio_"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radio_2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Home" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Battle and Brew, 5920 Roswell Road" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="The Fox Theatre, 660 Peachtree Street" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please note that you can change this from static to dynamic by using java in your activity to create these view elements and inflate them.

Here is a screenshot of the above code:
[image]

Comment: Why use nested layouts when you are within a ConstraintLayout? Flatten it.

Comment: Can you share the icons/drawable please?

Comment: @UnKnown you can right click on your drawable directory, and click on the vector asset option. Then, By clicking on the clip art button, you can import all the vector drawbles easily (they are available in the android studio by default).